# How to access wamp server on Internet

Tags: wamp

I am installed **Wamp** web server on server it works fine on localhost. But when I am trying to access it from the internet it doesn't get access. I am  trying to access it using a static IP address (eg: staticIP:8383/index.php) but without success. Right now we are accessing the server using a virtual address for **IIS**. Could you please provide me a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

#### This only applies to WampServer 2.5 or lower versions which are now well out of date

WAMPServer is designed as a single desk developer tool so to protect the beginner from themselves it comes with Apache configured to only allow access from the PC running WAMPServer.

If you want to allow access from anywhere all you have to do to change the Apache config to allow this, and there is a menu item to do this.

```
left click wampmanager -> Put Online
```

Give it a few seconds to make the change as it will restart Apache as part of the process.

You should now be able to acccess WampServers Apache from the internet.

You will of course have to port forward your router so that port 8383 is forwarded for TCP connections to the ip address of the PC running WAMPServer.

Comment: I am done with all necessary changes  1.first I put wamp server online   2.i am doing changes in httpd.config according  to below URL:(http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/395286/How-to-Access-WAMP-Server-in-LAN-or-WAN). and crete New Inbound Rule for Port no:8383 in Firewall setting. but i still face the problem.

Comment: Thats now a very good tutorial. That is talking only about making the CGI scripts available. I assume you are not using CGI and are using ordinary PHP scripts that live in folder. Have a look at this it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131224/how-to-bring-wamp-server-online